# Is it possible to connect to scylla using cassandra connector 3.10 using Catalog?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, scylla

I am trying to do a simple select in a scylla database as follows:

```
spark.read.table("Scylla.config.parameters").show(5)
```

I have created a variable with the settings that I will use as follows:

```
val sparkConf: SparkConf = new SparkConf()
.set(s"spark.sql.extensions", "com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraSparkExtensions")
.set(s"spark.sql.catalog.Scylla", "com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraCatalog")
.set(s"spark.sql.catalog.Scylla.spark.cassandra.connection.host", Settings.cassandraServerAddress)
.set(s"spark.sql.catalog.Scylla.spark.sql.catalog.spark.cassandra.auth.username", Settings.User)
.set(s"spark.sql.catalog.Scylla.spark.cassandra.auth.password", Settings.Pass)
.set(s"spark.sql.catalog.Scylla.spark.cassandra.connection.port",Settings.Port)

val sparkSession: SparkSession = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .config(sparkConf)
    .appName(Settings.appname)
    .getOrCreate()
```

Then I make the call to start the Spark Session:

```
val spark: SparkSession = Spark.sparkSession
```

But when the engine tries to execute the query, it returns the error:

```
Node node01-xxx-scylla.xxxxxxxx.com/xxx.x.xxx.xxx:9042 requires authentication (org.apache.cassandra.auth.PasswordAuthenticator), but no authenticator configured
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there an incompatibility of the connector version with the version of scylla I use? The version of scylla I am using is 2021.1.5-0.20210818.fc817c0cd

@Edit

I have identified the problem. In my db user configuration, I had too much text in the connection string. After adjustment the problem stopped.

Before:

```
.set(s"spark.sql.catalog.Scylla.spark.sql.catalog.spark.cassandra.auth.username", Settings.User)
```

After:

```
.set(s"spark.sql.catalog.Scylla.spark.cassandra.auth.username", Settings.User)
```

Comment: what version of cassandra connector?

Comment: libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "3.1.0",

Comment: I have identified the problem. In my db user configuration, I had too much text in the connection string. After adjustment the problem stopped.